# Actionscript flex: Converting # colors to uint

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm working with several components that take color as a uint, but the colors I have are in the format of "#161616". I'm not sure what the relation between the 2 types of colors are or how to go from one to another.

It doesn't have to be an actionscript solution. I have only a small number of these colors, so can be done manually too.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
var color:uint = 0x161616;
```

Or, to convert them programmatically:

```
var s:String = "#161616";
var color:uint = uint("0x" + s.substr(1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that stylesheets in Flex want the color values in the form #FFFFFF ... NOT 0xFFFFFF. MXML element style properties don't care. Although when you start writing something like:

```
<mx:VBox backgroundColor="
```

the Intellisense prompts you for a uint value; if you go ahead and complete it like so

```
<mx:VBox backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"></VBox>
```

it will still make your backgroundColor the same as if you had written

```
<mx:VBox backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF"></VBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are 2 of my utils functions:

```
    public static function convertUintToString( color:uint ):String {  
            return color.toString(16);  
    }  

    public static function convertStringToUint(value:String, mask:String):uint {  
            var colorString:String = "0x" + value;  
            var colorUint:uint = mx.core.Singleton.getInstance("mx.styles::IStyleManager2").getColorName( colorString );  

            return colorUint;  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the correct way is by using `StyleManager.getColorName()`
see the full [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/styles/StyleManager.html#getColorName%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
var i : uint = uint("0x161616");
```